# In Android, how to display a StatusBar/View to be used in multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-layout

Android newbie here. I have an existing legacy app in Swing that I wish to convert to an Android App. In the legacy app, I have a permanent StatusView in the bottom (outlined in yellow). The StatusView will remain displayed all throughout the application.

More background info.. The android application, an in-vehicle asset management terminal, will be a bit complex as it has a lot of Activities and background threads involved.  On application startup, it will connect to our backend thru socket based communication. The StatusView needs to display an image showing it is COMMS CONNECTED.  Also, on application startup, it will show if it is GPS CONNECTED.

In Android, how will I accomplish this? Will it be a fragment passed to each activity? Or will it be just a custom view created or passed on each activity? Is this possible?

[image: android-views]

Comment: A little bit related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790426/android-reusing-same-view-object-in-different-activities-the-case-is-about-ad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not a complicated app i.e if there is no real need to have multiple activities, then i would definitely recommend using a view in your xml layout for the status information and use fragments for rendering other pieces of information around your status view.

If you absolutely can't do the app with one activity, then i think you will have to create a fragment for your status information and then attach it to every activity. Remember that the fragment's lifecycle is connected and controlled with that of the activity it is attached to. So, you will have to attach/add your status fragment for each activity.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @user693959! If we use option 2 as described above, when the user goes from Activity1 to Activity2, does it mean I need to remove it from Activity1 and add it to Activity2?.. so on and so forth as I move across activities?

Comment: You don't have to remove it from Activity1 - the platform will handle it appropriately. But you do have to attach or add it to Activity 2. Look at the fragment lifecycle and activity lifecycle and how these two lifecycles are related. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Just create one view for that and use `<include ... />` to include that view to your Activity's layout. In each Activity you have to modify it independently.